# Putting two tables side-by-side with equal spacing

Tags: html, html-table

I'm quite new to Stack Overflow and am still learning programming. I would like to put two tables side-by-side with equal spacing and prevent the tables from touching the sides of the page. I wrote this code, but am not getting the right result:

```
<table style="float:right; background-color: white;font-family: cursive,sans-serif; border-radius: 8%; border-color: white" border="0" width="420px" height="216px" >

    <tr style='float: left; background-color: white; border-radius: 3%; border-color: white;' width='200px' height='54px'>
        <td style='font-family: cursive,sans-serif; border-color: white; ;' width='200px' height='54px'>From</td>
        <td style="font-family: cursive,sans-serif; border-color: white; border-radius: 3%" width='200px' height='54px'>To</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<table align="center" style=" float:left; background-color: white;font-family: cursive,sans-serif; border-radius: 8%; border-color: white" border="1" width="420px" height="216px">

</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome!

1. Move your styles into a .css file first of all.
2. I put together a little demo, [check it out](http://jsbin.com/epiqiz/1/edit) - don't mind the table:nth-child(2n) selectors, those could also be class names.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've done that already.Your demo was really helpful.But I dont really get the use of the nth-child.

Comment: Chris Coyier explains it better [here](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/). Essentially `table:nth-child(2n)` selects the second table element in the demo. `table:first-child` would select the first table. It's a CSS `pseudo` selector, you could just as easily give those tables class names and then change the CSS selectors to those class names and the demo would still work.

Comment: Okay...got that.Thank you.

Comment: Wow! What an answer. its pretty staright forward. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS3 for this task.  Do NOT use frames (they, in essence, been deprecated). You should do a search for this.  I found a good start on THIS site:

[Div side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6449521/div-side-by-side)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks a lot.gonna check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Set the two tables inside a container div with some `padding: 0 XXpx;`  where XX is the amount of spacing that you want.  For the tables to float properly, the width of this div must be at least 842px (the size of both floated tables plus the border of the first one).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I used margin-top and it works quite good.Thanks.

Comment: glad it worked, please consider marking my response as the solution if you want! Thanks.

Comment: I didnt use div because I didnt really know how to.Could you give me an example??...Thanks.

Comment: Here is an example of your code done with just divs.  Adjust the .container class accordingly to fit the intended page width.  http://jsfiddle.net/XQPXQ/3/

Comment: I now get it.Thanks a lot.