# Putting two rows and two columns in a table with an equal spacing

Tags: html, html-table

I am new to Stack Overflow and also a novice programmer. I would like to place two rows and two columns in a table with an equal spacing the first row contains two words and I need the second row to contains two text areas. Here's the little code I tried but am not getting it:

```
        <tr style='float: left; background-color: white; border-radius: 3%; border-color: white;' width='200px' height='54px'>
            <td style='font-family: cursive,sans-serif; border-color: white; ;' width='200px' height='54px'>From</td>
            <td style="font-family: cursive,sans-serif; border-color: white; border-radius: 3%" width='200px' height='54px'>To</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: You shouldn't reask the same question within 3 hours. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16992893/putting-two-tables-side-by-side-with-equal-spacing

Comment: They are different questions. I am not asking the same thing. The first question asked about two tables, while this present one is asking about rows and columns inside a table. Please read the question carefully. Thank you very much.